# I there a way to detect if an apk has been obfuscated?

Tags: android, obfuscation

I'm working on instrumenting apks for monitoring purposes.
is there a way to ascertain if an apk has been obfuscated?
I'm specifically looking for a way to check if it has been obfuscated by  junk byte injection obfuscation.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you can be hundred percent sure that an APK has been obfuscated :

- obfuscation is a complex process. You can either only shrink code, obfuscate and shrink, obfuscate a few classes only, it will really be hard to detect that only a few classes were obfuscated.
- another problem is that you don't know the names of the classes that may have been obfuscated. Usually obfuscation will change classes names to `a.a.a` for instance. But, maybe the source code was using the class `a.a.a` for real... Who knows ?

You could still get the list of all classes inside a dex inside an apk (using command line `dexdump | grep Descriptor`) and see if you can recognize some obfuscated class name patterns. That would give you a certain level of confidence.